# Kitchen faucet install

Tags: kitchens, faucet

Moen Adler 87233SRS single handle kitchen faucet. New install. Water live at stops but no water comes out of the faucet. Spray head not attached yet.

Comment: yes, you should attach the spray head and test again ... you didn't ask anything, so I asked for you

Comment: So what's the question?